# Why does log4j filter not works inside appender

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

I've create a custom filter that looks like this:

```
@Plugin(name = "EmptyMessageFilter", category = Node.CATEGORY, elementType = Filter.ELEMENT_TYPE, printObject = true)
public class EmptyMessageFilter extends AbstractFilter {

  @PluginFactory
  public static EmptyMessageFilter createFilter() {
    return new EmptyMessageFilter();
  }
...
}
```

The log4j config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <!-- When filter is here it works -->
    <Filters>
        <EmptyMessageFilter/>
    </Filters>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        <!-- When filter is here it does not work -->
        <Filters>
            <EmptyMessageFilter/>
        </Filters>  
        </Console>
  
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When the filter is configured inside the Console appender it does not work but when it's outside the appenders it works.
According to this https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Loggers both should work. Any hints whats wrong?

The predefined filters like RegexFilter or BurstFilter works as well inside the appender but i don't see a difference between my custom filter and the predifined filters....

Comment: Which methods does you `Filter` implement?

Comment: I have implementend all filter(...) methods from org.apache.logging.log4j.core.filter.AbstractFilter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Logback, which defines a separate [`Filter`](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/filter/Filter.html) and [`TurboFilter`](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/turbo/TurboFilter.html) interface, Log4j Core has a single [`Filter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/Filter.html) interface that has a **double purpose**:

- the [`filter(LogEvent)`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/Filter.html) method is used when the filter is:

  1. attached to an appender,
  2. attached to an appender reference,
  3. attached to a logger configuration (as in your case).
- the remaining `filter` methods are only used when your filter is a **global** filter (directly attached to a configuration).

Your `filter(LogEvent)` method must work incorrectly, hence the issue. Remark that in this case you **always** have a message (usually of type `ObjectMessage`, `SimpleMessage` or `ParameterizedMessage`), although this message might be a mutable one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you where right, filter(final LogEvent event) had an error. was not aware that global filter calls different methods than appender filter

Answer (score -1):

I think the `log4j` can not identify which `Filter` class in the xml, try to use the fully qualified class name of your extended Filter in the tag.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. The filter is found, just not when it's defined insinde console appender